# Rust: Need both events when a transaction is sent and when is confirmed

Tags: transactions, confirmations, rust

Rust.

For a method `send()` of a smart contract I need to process *both* events when the transaction is sent (and generates txhash) and when it is confirmed.

From https://docs.rs/ethcontract/0.7.2/ethcontract/transaction/enum.ResolveCondition.html it seems that `ethcontract` can trigger a future only on one of these conditions :-(

Is it possible to check both?